# Convert NSString to float - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I want to convert a string to float, here the code I wrote :

```
NSString *latString = [[response valueForKey:@"coords"] valueForKey:@"lat"];
NSLog(@"Latitude String: %@", latString);
self.coordLat = [latString floatValue];
NSLog(@"Latitude: %lu", (unsigned long) self.coordLat);
```

But Here is what I get:

```
2016-03-14 17:36:00.471 marsad[9968:186761] Latitude String: 36.860532
2016-03-14 17:36:00.587 marsad[9852:152630] Latitude: 36
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unsigned long` type are like `integers` so naturally the decimal point is truncated.

Try `NSLog(@"Latitude: %f", self.coordLat);` instead.

Comment: Sorry I am new to IOS, With what should I replace it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSString` `floatValue` readonly property, as described in [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/floatValue) :

> This property doesn’t include whitespace at the beginning of the string. This property is HUGE_VAL or –HUGE_VAL on overflow, 0.0 on underflow. This property is 0.0 if the string doesn’t begin with a valid text representation of a floating-point number.

If you string is properly formatted, you can then simply cast it to float using :

```
NSString *val = @"3.45";
float fCost = [val floatValue];
```

Comment: Generally speaking, some explanation of why this is the right answer will yield better results (more upvotes, more accepted answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Latitude: %lu", (unsigned long) self.coordLat);
```

This will convert the value to a long.
You should use something like:

```
NSLog(@"Latitude: %f", self.coordLat);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Latitude: %g", self.coordLat);
```

64-bit floating-point number (double), printed in the style of %e if the exponent is less than –4 or greater than or equal to the precision, in the style of %f otherwise.